# calculus of variations: does extremum squared give the same solution?

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Do the following two integrals have the same solution?
$J=\int^{{x}_2}_{{x}_1}f(y, \dot{y}, x)dx$,
$J=\int^{{x}_2}_{{x}_1}f(y, \dot{y}, x)^2dx$. Several questions, such as shortest line in a plane, shortest line on a sphere, minimum surface of revolution, have the same solution using the two integrals. But I cannot prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It depends on $f$. If function does not take negative values, extrema will be achieved at the same points for $f^2$ because $x^2$ is strictly increasing function, i.e. $x_1>x_2 \implies x_1^2>x_2^2$ and vise versa